# how to repeat the id for the length of an array in nodeJS and knexJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, knex.js

I want to add an array of items with the same `orderId`, so I need to have the `orderId` repeated for the length of the array, how do I do that?

My code:

```
const handleOrdersPost = (req, res, db) => {
const { customerId, orderStatus, productId, quantity, price} = req.body;
    if (!customerId || !orderStatus || !productId || !quantity || !price) {
        return res.status(400).json('incorrect form submission');
    }

    db.transaction(trx =>{
        trx.insert({
            customerId: customerId,
            orderStatus: orderStatus,
            orderDate: new Date()
            })
        .into('orders')
        .returning('orderId')
        .then(orderId => {
            return trx('orderitem')
            .returning('*')
            .insert({
                orderId: orderId,
                productId: [productId],
                quantity: [quantity],
                price: [price]
                })
            .then(order => {
            res.json('success');
            })
        })
        .then(trx.commit)
        .catch(trx.rollback)
    })


    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to submit order ' + err))
}

module.exports = {
    handleOrdersPost: handleOrdersPost
};
```

When I try to add multiple items using postman I get an error saying basically what I already know, that I need to repeat the id for the length of the array, because it works fine with just one item but I need it to work with multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

In one transaction, a bunch of insertion items' ids will and should be ordered, so you have to loop your array and count the `orderId`

so your code may looks like:

```
const array = [];
db.transaction((trx) => {
  db.insert([])
  .into('orders')
  .transacting(trx)
  .then((ids) => {
    const orderItems = [];
    orderItems.forEach((item, index) => {
      item.orderId = ids[0] + index;
    })；
    return db.insert(orderItems)
    .into('orderItem)
    .transacting(trx);
  })
  .then(trx.commit)
  .catch(trx.rollback);
})
```